LSTM Prediction Issue: Not Predicting Last Record and Backward Prediction Behavior
I'm conducting some tests with LSTM for learning purposes, but I've encountered a peculiar situation while testing its predictions.
I've observed in the graph images that it doesn't predict the last record and instead forecasts "backwards" from the first record.
In the first image, it shows predictions for the last 60 records. Later, when I added 61 records for prediction, I noticed it forecasts backward from the first record as if predicting data in the opposite direction.
What's odd is that I reversed the sequence of records in last_data, and after prediction, I reversed the results to maintain the correct order, hoping it would predict "in the opposite direction," and I could achieve the desired result with a workaround, but the outcome remained the same. It seems something is causing it to predict data in the way that suits it best!
The data I'm using to train is the opening and closing prices of stocks. From the results in the images, it seems that it can predict well, but this problem of not being able to predict the last record and predict the correct value before the first record is strange. To train the model I am using a csv with 6080 records.
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

# Load CSV data
base = pd.read_csv('dados_preparados.csv')

model_name = 'modelo_lstm.keras'

# Normalize data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
normalized_base = scaler.fit_transform(base[['val1', 'val2', 'result']].values)

closing_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
closing_normalized = closing_scaler.fit_transform(base[['result']].values)


if not os.path.exists(model_name):

    # Separate normalized data
    X = normalized_base[:, :-1]  # All columns except the last one (result)
    y = normalized_base[:, -1]   # The last column (result)

    # Reshape for LSTM format (samples, timesteps, features)
    X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]))

    # Create LSTM model
    regressor = Sequential()
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=300, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Dropout for regularization
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=100))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Dropout for regularization
    regressor.add(Dense(units=4, activation='relu'))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

    regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

    # Define callbacks
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=1e-10, patience=10, verbose=2)
    rlr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, verbose=2)
    mcp = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.h5', monitor='loss', save_best_only=True, verbose=2)

    # Train the model
    regressor.fit(X, y, epochs=30, batch_size=50, callbacks=[es, rlr, mcp], verbose=2)

    regressor.save(model_name)

# Load trained model
regressor = load_model(model_name)

# Make predictions with the latest training data
last_data = normalized_base[-120:-60, :-1]  # Last 60 records, all columns except the last one
last_data = np.reshape(last_data, (last_data.shape[0], 1, last_data.shape[1]))

predicted_normalized = regressor.predict(last_data)

# Inverse normalization to get actual values
predictions = closing_scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_normalized)

# Plot results
plt.plot(base['result'].values[-120:-60], color='red', label='Actual Price', linewidth=0.5, marker='o', markersize=1)
plt.plot(predictions, color='blue', label='Predictions', linewidth=0.5, marker='o', markersize=1)
plt.title('Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Yahoo Value')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('prediction.png')



See that on the right side the last prediction record appears to be missing and on the left side there appears to be one more prediction.

See that with 1 more record to predict the Current Price it was the same as predicted in the first image. If I make the next forecast by adding one more record, the Current Price at the beginning will have the predicted value at the beginning of the previous forecast.
What could be causing this error that makes it not predict the last record even though I invert the list of records?
